# is possible share users between ios and android projects in firebase for the authentication

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have one application for ios and andriod but in firebase are two projects. The problem is that if an user is registered in android app using firebase, in the ios app this user does not exist. So if the user want to sigin in the ios app she/he will not be able.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you associate the Android and iOS apps with the same Firebase project, the users will be the same between the apps.

If you associate the apps with separate projects, there is no way to automatically share the users between them.

Comment: ok I was confused about projects and apps on firebase I didn't know that was possible add many apps to a project, thanks.